# pdfkit doc.text showing "Ð" in newline (\n) in nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

I am using pdfkit to create invoice in pdf.

When I tried to add newline/nextline (\n) in a string which I tried to add using `doc.text("Text \n new line");` it shows Ð and then adds newline.

Here is the code:

```js
const doc = new PDFDocument({
    margin: 5,
    autoFirstPage: false,
    bufferPages: true,
});

doc.addPage();

// other codes ...


doc.text("1. Hello World");
doc.text(`2. Pdfkit
newline`);
```

Here is the rendered screenshot:

[image]

How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
doc.text(`2. Pdfkit
newline`.replace(/\r\n|\r/g, '\n'));
```

I simply added `string.replace(/\r\n|\r/g, '\n')` for the string and it worked

Reference: https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit/issues/606

Comment: Does the trick for me.